# How to start a process/application on windows connection change event using C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I can detect the network connection change event while running a C# code, how would I register an exe when Windows detects this event. What all details would I need. Below is how I am using this :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;


    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                testing t = new testing();
                Console.Read();

            }
        }
        public class testing{
            public testing()
            {
                NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
            }

            void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.IsAvailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("network is available");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could maybe do is in your method that is triggered to start a new process and execute your exe

Comment: I do not want this code running all the time and waiting for the event to raise. I want this be handelled by the Window itself. So I need help which can register my exe on Windows Network change event.